# Ember: dumplicated records are created in store after model save action

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, one-to-many

I have two models in my ember app:

```
App.Order = DS.Model.extend  
  orderItems: DS.hasMany('orderItem')  


App.OrderItem = DS.Model.extend
  order: DS.belongsTo('order')
```

I tried to save orderItem,  bellow is the payload I got after save invoking.

```
{
  orderItem:{
    id:1
    order:"1"
  },
  orders:[
    {
      id:"1",
      orderItems:["1","2","3"]
    }
  ],
  orderItems:[
    {
      id:"1",
      order:"1"
    },
    {
      id:"2",
      order:"1"
    },
    {
      id:"3",
      order:"1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, I found 2 duplicated orderItems records in ember store with same id(id=1).
I don't know how does ember push payload after model saving. 
error will be shown if removing orderItem(id=1) from orderItems hash.

Who can tell me what's the root cause?